# How to get bash ssh version number only?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Running `ssh -V` gives me:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0i-fips  14 Aug 2018
```

Now I would like to get just

```
7.6
```

to allow me to compare version numbers.

**NOTE**: I needed the ssh version number to allow me to compare it in my bash scripts. Since I didn't find an easy solution online, I thought it would be nice to document this for future users as a [self-answered Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: Could I get some comments on the downvotes? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps it wasn't clear that this is self-answered Q&A and expected that you'd add your own attempts to the question, especially as someone with high reputation score. May be add a note that you faced this issue and thought your solution would be helpful for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested in GNU `awk`).

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[_,]' '{print $2+0}'
```

where $2+0 means it will look for maximum match of digits only and remove text after it. Which will provide exact version of ssh.

Comment: That's a good one ++. It should work for BSD awk also not just gnu-awk.

Comment: Can you explain the $2+0?

Comment: `$2+0` discards trailing non-numeric characters from 2nd field and returns only numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` also:

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | awk -F '[^0-9.]+' '{print $2}'
```

```
7.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | sed 's/OpenSSH_\([^p]*\)p.*/\1/'
```

explanation:

- `2>&1` : for some strange reason `ssh` prints the version info to stderr; we redirect to stdout to allow parsing.
- `\([^p]*\)` : take all characters that are not a **p**.

Answer (score 0):

Or with pure Bash Regex:

```
[[ $(ssh -V 2>&1) =~ [0-9.]+ ]];echo $BASH_REMATCH
```